# get »className« from rule

Tags: typescript, jss

Here is the basic setup:

```
import { create, Rule, StyleSheet } from 'jss';
import preset from 'jss-preset-default';
import global from 'jss-plugin-global';

const jss = create(preset()).use(global());
const sheet = jss.createStyleSheet({}, { link: true });


const rules = sheet.addRules({button: { display: 'none' }});

console.log(rules.map(r => r.className)) // [undefined]
```

As described in the doce [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api?v=v10.7.1#add-a-rule-dynamically) `className` should be there, but it isn't. So, how can I get that classname, such that I can build an Object that like `sheet.classes`, but only with the newly added rules? In this case:

```
{
  button: 'some-crazy-generated-classname'
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found that those `Rule` objects created by `addRule` / `addRules` have a `key` and `selector` property, which basically does that, but the typings does not reflect that, so it does not feel right to use those.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an older version that doesn't have that property? The "API" docs don't seem to have a clear summary of what a `rule` object has, but I did eventually find an example of `className` being used on a rule from `addRule`, so as you say, it should be there. The linked docs are for v10.7.1.

Comment: But I am using 10.7.1 - installed this morning. latest

Comment: Ah, well. Figured it was best to check. :-)

Comment: Looking at the typesctipt declaration shows that there not such property

Comment: Sounds like a documentation error then.

Comment: That may very well be - but what is the way to access the classname now?? The Objects have `key` and `selector` property that works, but typescript doesn't know about it.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use that lib. But it does kind of make sense. After all, class rules are only *one kind* of rule, so `selector` makes sense to me rather than `className`. Odd if it's missing from the type information.

Comment: But which lib are you using for such purpose??

Comment: I don't. ......